# MySQL query: ORDER BY date plus other record

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a table with:

```
last_billed DATE DEFAULT "0000-00-00"
bill_interval varchar(10) DEFAULT "Monthly" (other values are: Quarterly, Half-yearly, Yearly)
```

I run a simple query, but it needs to:

```
ORDER BY (last_billed + bill_interval)
```

This should give a date which is 1 month, 3 months, 6 months or 12 months further then the last_billed date, depending on the value of bill_interval.
Now I can change bill_interval to anything if need be, if it would make the query possible.

I have no idea where to start with this. So any feedback is, as always, appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ORDER BY last_billed + 
    CASE bill_interval
        WHEN "Montly" THEN INTERVAL 1 MONTH
        WHEN "Half-Yearly" THEN INTERVAL 6 MONTH
        WHEN "Yearly" THEN INTERVAL 1 YEAR
    END
```

It would be easier if you changed the `bill_interval` column to a number of months, then you could do:

```
ORDER BY last_billed + INTERVAL bill_interval MONTH
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Did what you said too. Changed it to a single number.
Thanks a bunch again!

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY DateAdd("m", 
  case substring(bill_interval,1,1) when 'M' then 1 
                                    when 'Q' then 3 
                                    when 'Y' then 12 
  end, last_billed)
```